# How to convert format of an array of objects

Tags: jquery, json

I have variable which has data from JSON as below:

```js
 var dictionary = {
     "data": [{ "id": "0", "name": "ABC" }, { "id": "1", "name": "DEF" }],
     "images": [{ "id": "0", "name": "PQR" }, { "id": "1", "name": "xyz" }]
 };
```

I want to split above json data using jquery and get them stored in three variables col[0], col[1]
i want this result:

```js
var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(dictionary);
var col = [];
col[0] = [{
  "id": "0",
  "name": "ABC"
}, {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "DEF"
}]
col[1] = [{
  "id": "0",
  "name": "PQR"
}, {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "xyz"
}]
```

this my code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
  for (var key in dictionary[i]) {
    if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
      col.push(key);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: iam part solve  this problem when edit post is clean

Comment: Please share valid `dictionary` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()`.

```js
var dictionary = {
     "data": [{ "id": "0", "name": "ABC" }, { "id": "1", "name": "DEF" }],
     "images": [{ "id": "0", "name": "PQR" }, { "id": "1", "name": "xyz" }]
 };
 
var col = Object.values(dictionary);
console.log(col);
```